# DB2 concat vs double pipe

Tags: performance, db2, double, pipe, concatenation

Which one of this two views require less CPU?

I'm currently checking the sentences of some views and need to know if there is some performance improvement if concat functions are replaced by double pipes.

```
create view VIEW1 as
select concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(concat(A, B),C),D),E),F),F),G),H),I) from TABLE

create view VIEW2 as
select A||B||C||D||E||F||G||H||I from TABLE
```

Comment: I would be **very** surprised if there was any measruable performance difference.

Comment: Is concat function the same as the concat operator? Probably the performance difference is ther http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000781.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-4-1-25 - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000736.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-2-10 Concat operator is an alias to concat function? then calling an alias is a little more expensive. But I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Information Center](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_concat.html):

> The CONCAT function is identical to the CONCAT operator. For more
> information, see [With the concatenation operator](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_withconcatoperator.html#db2z_withconcatoperator).

So, the definitive answer is: they're the same. However, IBM does have this to say:

> Vertical bars (or the characters that must be used in place of
> vertical bars in some countries) can cause parsing errors in
> statements passed from one DBMS to another. The problem occurs if the
> statement undergoes character conversion with certain combinations of
> source and target CCSIDs. Thus, CONCAT is the preferable
> concatenation operator.

Comment: You're answering all of my DB2 questions before I ask them.

Comment: CONCAT is NOT identical to the `||` operator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934762/string-concatenation-with-a-null-seems-to-nullify-the-entire-string-is-that-de

Comment: @NikaKasradze that is PostgreSQL-specific. DB2's docs say 
> The result can be null; if any argument is null, the result is the null value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there will be performance difference, but using pipes-makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do

create view VIEW1 as
select A concat B concat C concat D concat E concat F concat F concat G concat H concat I from TABLE

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about performance but they behave differently when dealing with `null` values. See: [String concatenation with a null seems to nullify the entire string - is that desired behavior in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934762/string-concatenation-with-a-null-seems-to-nullify-the-entire-string-is-that-de)