# String concatenation with a null seems to nullify the entire string - is that desired behavior in Postgres?

Tags: string, postgresql, concatenation

In Postgres:

```
select 'test' || null  returns null
```

I was expecting it would otherwise return 'test'.

Is this desired behavior? Seems weird that string concatenation with a null value would nullify the entire string...

Referring to pg docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

> "Note: Before PostgreSQL 8.3, these functions would silently accept values of several non-string data types as well, due to the presence of implicit coercions from those data types to text. Those coercions have been removed because they frequently caused surprising behaviors. However, the string concatenation operator (||) still accepts non-string input, so long as at least one input is of a string type, as shown in Table 9-6. For other cases, insert an explicit coercion to text if you need to duplicate the previous behavior."

Given that, using their concat string function example:

concat(str "any" [, str "any" [, ...] ])
text    Concatenate all arguments. NULL arguments are ignored.  concat('abcde', 2, NULL, 22) >> abcde222

Should I just get used to this behavior with '||' concatenation or is this something that should be fixed?

Comment: It's not only "desired", this is how it is specified in the SQL standard.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - that it is SQL standard is all I really needed to know - your comment should be the answer. Seems unintuitive though. It challenged me to have a look at how other languages handle that case. C# seems to offer the intuitive - treating the null as a zero-length string. Javascript and Java concatenate "null" to your string (sheesh).

Comment: just for fun i'd like to add, aggregates seem to ignore null ;)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Quote from documentation

> Concatenate all arguments. NULL arguments are ignored.

Example

```
concat('abcde', 2, NULL, 22)
```

Returns

```
abcde222
```

See more in [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)

Comment: It helps and is most simple for this case.

Comment: there's a side effect though, considering that concat will never return NULL, e.g. `concat(null,null)` returns `''` (empty string)

Answer (score 32):

It's not a bug and it's not "weird".

The SQL standard requires any expression that involves `null` yields `null`. This is not limited to string concatenation, it also applies to computations e.g.: `42 * null` returns `null`.

This also applies to comparisons: `42 > null` yields `null`. So the comparison it's neither true nor false. Although in reality this has the effect of "false", but more because it's "not true", rather then false. But negating such an expression yields `null` again, not "true".

Because `null` is so special, the only way to check if something is null is to use the operator `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`. `x is null` yields either true or false, it never yields `null`, so expressions using the `is null` or `is not null` operator *never* return null - so this is an exception to my statement above (thanks Jonathan for pointing that out).

---

Another - maybe surprising - fact about `null` values is how they are handled by aggregate functions. While the *expression* `4 + 5 + null` yields null, the `sum()` over those (column) values would yield 9, because aggregates *ignore* `null`  values.

Given the following table:

```
    col1
--------
       1
       2
       3 
     null
```

`sum(col1)` will return 6, and `avg(col1)` will return `2` (sum = 6, number of elements added: 3)

Comment: Using _any_ is a little bit of an over-statement, though not by much.  Amongst the exceptions are `x IS NULL` and `x IS NOT NULL` and their relatives.  And the key point about `x > 42` when `x` is null is that the row isn't selected, but it also isn't selected when you filter on `x < 42` — to select all the rows, you need `x > 42 OR x < 42 OR x IS NULL`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: regarging `>` vs. `<` that's what I wanted to get across when I mentioned that this isn't "false", but no true. Regarding the "any expression". Is there a term that distinguishes between `x > null` and `x is not null`? I feel they are something similar, but I can't name it ;)

Answer (score 23):

Yes, it is desired behavior.

Here is an example in which it is very useful. Let's say you have a persons table an in it the fields `title`, `firstname`, `nameaffix` and `lastname`. To build a full name you can simply do this.

```
COALESCE(title || ' ', '') || firstname || COALESCE(' ' || nameaffix, '') || ' ' || lastname
```

Without that strange behavior that would be quite an effort to place the spaces at the right spots depending on whether a field is null or not. Assuming a mandatory first name and last name any combination of title and name affix is covered.

Comment: Using `concat_ws(',', title, firstname, nameaffix, lastname)` is even simpler

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh, great! 'Invented' the example in 8.4 and never looked for a function ever since. Works since 9.1, that is. Thank you!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name careful with CONCAT_WS if you're trying to get a csv view of your table row. I tried this and when a column was null it was simply omitted putting my column ordering off. Every column to the right-hand side of the first null was shifted.

Comment: You can also use this to your advantage if you want to skip certain entries: Exclude them with `NULLIF(case_statement, replacement)`, e.g. `concat_ws(',', NULLIF(CASE WHEN title = 'Mr Bombastic' THEN '' ELSE title END, ''), firstname, ...)`

Answer (score 5):

As the guy who taught me SQL said, "NULL means 'unknown' it doesn't mean 'zero', or 'empty string' it means 'unknown'".

That is the reason it is desired behavior, the result of combining something with an unknown value is an unknown.

This is also worth considering when designing new columns and what being nullable means for them.

Comment: This is outdated. NULL is now ignored instead of returning NULL

Comment: @ZhuHang I'm using version 9.6, for me NULLs are ignored if using the concat() function but not when using the double pipe || as the original poster does.
So 
SELECT concat('a',NULL,'b');
returns 'ab'
SELECT 'a' || NULL || 'b';
returns NULL

Comment: @zhuhang.jasper It's still a valid advice for PG12. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-comparison.html

Answer (score 4):

```
select 'test' || coalesce(null::text ,'')  return test
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

To concat with nullable attribute you can use next construction:

```
select 'test-' || coalesce(nullable_attr::text, 'null');
```

if `nullable_atr` is `null` it returns `test-null`

if `nullable_attr` is not `null`, e.g 'test_2' it returns `test-test_2`