# Concat Multiple columns into one

Tags: postgresql

I would like to concat multiple columns into a single column. When a value is Null I wish not to show it but I do want to show the values that exist. I couldn't find an example stackoverflow, below is a table of result set I'm trying to get, however, in this case because the "email" is null the entire result set is null not sure why this is occurring. I apologize in advance for my table if it doesn't display properly I've been using senseful github to create my table(s) but when I copy and paste here it displays weird.

```sql
SELECT
    Id,
    'study_id:' || study_id ||' , ' || 'email:' || email ||' , ' || 'phone:' || phone AS "Longvalue",
FROM
    mv_itest mi
```

| id | Longvalue |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | `study_id:123 , phone:123-123-1234` |

This is the result set if I use concat, however, I do not wish to display the alias for phone if the value is null

+-----+-----------------------+--+
| id  |       longvalue       |  |
+-----+-----------------------+--+
| 987 | study_id:456 , phone: |  |
+-----+-----------------------+--+

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String concatenation with a null seems to nullify the entire string - is that desired behavior in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934762/string-concatenation-with-a-null-seems-to-nullify-the-entire-string-is-that-de)

Comment: ISO SQL's `||` operator immediately returns `NULL` if _any_ of the operands `IS NULL` (yes, I think this painful-by-default design is another demonstration of the ISO SQL commitee's latent sadism) - the solution is to use `CONCAT()` instead, which behaves like you want.

Comment: Well the only issue with Concat is that if I hardcode the column alias it will display the alias but with no value. @Dai so it would be like study_id:123 , email: , phone:123-123-1234 and I'm trying not to show the value when is null.

Comment: Use concat() or concat_ws() and your problem is gone. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html

Comment: By the way, imho presentation should be done in the presentation layer, not in the database.

Comment: @CerealBox You wrote: _"Well the only issue with Concat is that if I hardcode the column alias it will display the alias but with no value."_ - I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: @FrankHeikens sorry I don't understand your last response

Comment: `select concat('phone: ', '1234', ', ',  'email: ', coalesce(NULL, '')); phone: 1234, email: ` **Or** `select 'phone: ' || '1234' || ', ' ||  'email: ' || coalesce(NULL, ''); phone: 1234, email:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want something like a json result, you might do that using JSON functions (it is already explained concatting NULL would yield null):

```
select id,
       regexp_replace(
               jsonb_strip_nulls(
                       jsonb_build_object(
                               'study_id:', study_id,
                               'email:', email,
                               'phone:', phone
                           ))::text, '[{}"]', '', 'g') as "longvalue"
from mv_itest mi;
```